# Почему при установке плагина Autoptimize, меняются заголовки страницы?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Почему после установки плагина Autoptimize выводятся заголовки которые написаны для SEO через плагин All in One SEO. Если удалить плагин то выводятся Названия страниц. Как это можно исправить отключить?

Заголовки выводятся через функцию wp_title('')
Может кто то сталкивался?
При включенном плагине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если плагин выключен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если переключится на стандартную тему WP. Проблема останется?

Comment: @Алексей да
Понял в чем проблема, я использовал wp_title а нужно было the_title();
Спасибо ваш комментарий привел к решению)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно выводить заголовок через `the_title();`.
У меня было `wp_title`.